# Fancybox dailymotion, can't fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a link and a JS code for open an iframe fancybox with a Dailymotion video :

```
<a class="vid" id="x4il536">Video</a>
```

And the JS :

```
                $('.vid').click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');

                    $.fancybox({
                        'type' : 'iframe',
                        // 'width'     : 640,
                        // 'height'        : 480,
                        'href'          : 'https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/'+id
                    });
                });
```

This code is working, when I click on my link, fancybox open my video but the **button fullscreen** has no effect.

Any ideas ? I can control volume, quality etc.. but not the fullscreen mode. I can see thebutton but no effect when I click.